# Show a different choice for each target role

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I am trying to make it so that a different choice is shown for each target role.

In the example, I would like it to show Mandatory for the QMP and Optional for the PM. Is this achievable in a SharePoint list?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this on list forms? You will have to customize the list forms using Power Apps to achieve your requirements. check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

Comment: Whether you mean when choosing QMP in the Target Role column, the Required column will show Mandatory?

Comment: Yes. I would like to show to the users that the material is Mandatory for QMP, but Optional for PM.